# DNN website: one user fails login because aspnet_membership.isapproved is default 0

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Running a website on DNN. 
One user cannot login. What might be the problem here.

I found a solution online saying
The field aspnet_membership.isapproved was set to ZERO even though dnn_userportals.authorized was set to 1. Once I changed 0 to 1 the login worked. Where and how to change aspnet_membership.isapproved? Is it in the code or user interface on the website.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting that admin can change. Apparrently DNN has 4 types of user registration.

1. None:

   This removes the registration link from your website. The administrators of your website can only add new users manually.
2. **Private (your site uses this)**:

   The register link appears. When a user registers, the administrators have to approve the user before the user will be granted access.
3. Public:

   This is the default setting for your DotNetNuke portal. The register link appears. When a user registers, they are given instant access to your site as a member without any verification.
4. Verified:

   The registration link appears. When a user registers, they are sent an email with a verification code. The first time they login, they are asked to enter the verification code, if they are verified correctly; they are given access to your site as a member. Once they are verified, they no longer need to enter the verification code

Do the steps below

- Login as admin
- Go to the admin menu / site settings
- Scroll down to ‘advanced settings’ – click on the plus button
- Under 'security settings' and 'user registration' click on the registration option you require (**You need Public or Verified**)
- Scroll down and click on the update button

This is the [Reference](http://www.dnncreative.com/DNNUsersSettingtheRegistrationOptions/tabid/89/Default.aspx).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are an admin you can edit the user under user accounts and select "Authorize".

Answer (score 0):

Our DNN is integrated with a single sign on solution.  Users are created both online and through our association management system by our staff interally.

When faced with this problem, updating the "Authorised" value to true using the DNN admin failed due to an unseen date value not being properly handled.

While the original problem seems to still exist for us the fix was to update the Authorised bit:
UPDATE
    userportals 
SET authorised = 1, refreshroles=0
    WHERE userid = 73348

User logged in with no problem on the next try.

hope this helps

ESD